# Converter binário em decimal sem usar "parseInt()"

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, conversão

Estou tentando fazer um *script* de conversão de números binário em decimal. Sei que usar `parseInt()` é o suficiente, mas não é o que eu quero aqui.

Aparentemente o código tinha dado certo, mas quando o numero binário termina com `0`, o resultado é um número errado.

```
let bin = '1110';
let dec = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < bin.length; c++) {
  if (bin[c] == 1) {
    dec += Math.pow(2, c);
  };
}

console.log(dec);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O maior problema é que não está pegando os caracteres na ordem correta, está pegando o primeiro e fazendo o expoente com a menor grandeza quando o primeiro caractere é o de maior grandeza, então tem que inverter o cálculo do expoente ou pegar os caracteres ao contrário, que foi o que eu optei. Ainda tem como varrer o laço ao contrário começando do fim para o começo, mas não acho que vale a pena, ainda teria dois casos ao contrário e precisaria ter uma cálculo a fazer.

Não é um erro, mas não precisa de `if`, basta matemática, se os valores só podem ser 0 ou 1 multiplicado por 0 sempre dá 0 e multiplicando por 1 sempre dá o próprio valor.

Só um último comentário: o que você está fazendo é um *parse* de um texto que tem um padrão que presume-se ser uma notação binária de um número e quer converter para número, ponto, não número. Número é número, notação é notação, então existe uma notação decimal, mas não existe um número decimal.

A forma simples, eficiente (não faz alocações de memória e processamento para manipular a *string*) e matemática pura seria assim (se é um exercício que não pode usar recursos da biblioteca acho que seria assim):

```js
let bin = '1110';
let dec = 0;
for (let c = 0; c < bin.length; c++) dec += Math.pow(2, c) * bin[bin.length - c - 1]; //calcula para pegar do último ao primeiro
console.log(dec);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Bin2Dec.ja).

Answer (score 5):

O seu problema é que você está fazendo a conversão de binário para decimal "ao contrário".

No sistema numérico binário, para se converter um número para o sistema numérico decimal, devemos, da **direita para a esquerda**, multiplicar cada *bit* pela potência de dois elevado a sua posição.

Então, na realidade, você está convertendo o binário `0111` (que é 7), já que está fazendo de trás para a frente.

Então, basta começar pelo inverso:

```js
function toDecimal(bin) {
  let dec = 0;

  for (let c = bin.length - 1, i = 0; c >= 0; c--, i++) {
    dec += bin[c] * Math.pow(2, i);
  }

  return dec;
}

console.log(
  toDecimal('1101010'),
  toDecimal('1101010') === parseInt('1101010', 2)
);
```

<sup>Essa abordagem foi sugerida pelo [@hkotsubo nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445566/converter-bin%C3%A1rio-em-decimal-sem-usar-parseint/445573#comment856390_445573) desta resposta.</sup>

---

Uma outra opção seria converter a *string* em um *array*, invertê-lo e reduzi-lo ao número decimal:

```js
function toDecimal(bin) {
  const reversed = bin.split('').reverse();
  let dec = 0;

  for (let c = 0; c < reversed.length; c++) {
    if (reversed[c] === '1') {
      dec += Math.pow(2, c);
    }
  }

  return dec;
}

console.log(
  toDecimal('1101010'),
  toDecimal('1101010') === parseInt('1101010', 2)
);
```

Obviamente essa última forma é menos eficiente, já que temos que converter a *string* para array, invertê-lo e realizar as operações.

Comment: Não era mais fácil começar o loop com o `bin.length - 1 ` e ir decrementando `c` até chegar a zero? Não precisa inverter a string...

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu pensei em fazer isso, mas não daria para usar o índice na potência sem fazer o cálculo que o Maniero fez na resposta dele. Acabaria dando num problema similar ao da pergunta. [Veja aqui.](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-445566)

Comment: É só criar outra variável pro expoente :-) Acho melhor que inverter a string (ainda mais que o JavaScript não tem um método nativo e faz a gente ter que criar  um array...)

Comment: Obrigada LuizFelipe e @Maniero vou fazer alguns testes implementando a soluções de vocês, sou iniciante então estou apanhando com algumas coisas ainda. Obrigada pelas explicações.